# Как правильно обновлять access (JWT) токен в SPA?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Есть SPA. Для того, чтобы юзеру не пришлось каждый раз перелогиниваться, сначала смотрю, не просрочен ли у него токен:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use( (config) => {
  if (jwt.isTokenExpired()) {
    api.refreshToken()
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.error == 'TOKEN_BLACKLISTED' && res.headers.authorization) {
          let token = res.headers.authorization
          jwt.setToken(`"${token}"`)
          api.setHeader()
        } else {
          jwt.destroyToken()
          jwt.destroyExpiredTime()
          store.dispatch('auth/destroyToken')
          router.push({name: 'login'})
        }
      })
  }
  return config;
}, function (error) {      
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Проблема в том, что `api.refreshToken()` - это тот же самый axios, поэтому идет бесконечный цикл: интерцептор перехватывает и вызывает сам у себя `api.refreshToken()`. Вопрос: как это решить? Можно ли отключить на какой-либо запрос перехват интерцептором запроса?